# name 'user' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to make a custom registration page without using usercreationform i've made the model and imported it but when i run it I keep encountering this error
NameError at /register
name 'user' is not defined
the line in particular is:
if user.password != user.repassword:

and i tried changing the method to GET instead of POST and i got a different error MultiValueDictKeyError 'fname'

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import User
from django.contrib import messages




def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def register(request):
    global user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User()
        user.fname = request.POST['fname']
        user.lname = request.POST['lname']
        user.email = request.POST['email']
        user.password = request.POST['password']
        user.repassword = request.POST['repassword']

    if user.password != user.repassword:
        return redirect("register")
    elif user.fname == "" or user.password == "" :
        messages.info(request,f"some fields are empty")
        return redirect("register")
    else:
        user.save()
    return render(request, 'register.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    repassword=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

html page

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load static%}

{%block content%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/style.css'%}">
<form method="post">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your First Name"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Enter your Last Name"><br>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email"><br>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter a password"><br>
    <label for="repassword">Re Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="repassword" placeholder="Re enter your password"><br>
    <button class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: You only assign a value to `user` under the condition `request.method == 'POST'` - but then you use it unconditionally throughout the rest of the function.  Perhaps the rest of the code needs to be indented one more level, so that it's also part of the `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something if the request method is not `POST`:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import BadRequest

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User()
        user.fname = request.POST['fname']
        user.lname = request.POST['lname']
        user.email = request.POST['email']
        user.password = request.POST['password']
        user.repassword = request.POST['repassword']
       
        if user.password != user.repassword:
            return redirect("register")
        elif user.fname == "" or user.password == "" :
            messages.info(request,f"some fields are empty")
            return redirect("register")

        user.save()
        return render(request, 'register.html')
    else:
        raise BadRequest()  # Or do something else
```

This view will work with `POST` requests.

Comment: how do you change the request method to POST

Comment: @hillaryetafo in your html page you are already doing a POST request: `<form method="post">`. What error is raised now?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?:

```
def register(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User()
        user.fname = request.POST['fname']
        user.lname = request.POST['lname']
        user.email = request.POST['email']
    ....
    ....
```